# Filtering LCHR fields behaves differently across ABAP versions

Tags: database, abap, sap-basis

When running the below SELECT statement I get following compilation error on ABAP 750 system

[image]

```
SELECT *
  INTO TABLE ltush04
  FROM ush04
   AND profs LIKE 'C%'.
```

However, it perfectly compiles on ABAP 701 but gives the following  **DBIF_RSQL_INVALID_RSQL** dump on execution

[image]

It is quite logical as one commonly knows this feature is not yet implemented (if ever will be).

Is it something SAP missed in previous releases (not-caught error) and improved now, or it was made deliberately, i.e. this statement is still valid on some DB-backends?

A line in a dump description suggested me that idea:

> In an SAP Open SQL statement, a "long field" was used in a way that is not supported by all database systems.

Comment: RSYN improved to avoid Runtime error most likely. Well if you have a kernel < 7.5 and it compiled, then the question answers itself ;)  If you are curious you could wade through the release notes. https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abennews.htm

Comment: Open SQL proposes functions which are the greatest common denominator (GCD) of functions of all supported databases by ABAP, so the short dump "suggestion" says everything. If in the future, the versions of supported databases evolve, then Open SQL is also updated to keep being the GCD. If your database supports this feature, then you may still directly access the database (so-called "native SQL" via ADBC, AMDP, etc.)